# Excel sheet script (online, no macros) that jumps to a given cell and positions it to the top, as it was A1

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I'm trying to write an excel sheet script (online, no macros) that jumps to a168 and positioning it to the top, as it was a1 cell

I tried the following so far, and it jumps to the cell but not positioning it to the top. Ideally it would jump where usually a1 cell is (top left)

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get the active worksheet
  let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // Define the target cell address
  let targetCellAddress = "A168";

  // Get the range of the target cell
  let targetCell = activeSheet.getRange(targetCellAddress);

  // Get the used range of the active sheet
  let usedRange = activeSheet.getUsedRange();

  // Calculate the number of rows to scroll to bring the target cell to the top
  let numRowsToScroll = targetCell.getRowIndex() - usedRange.getRowIndex();

  if (numRowsToScroll > 0) {
    // Create a range in the first row of the visible range
    let firstRowRange = usedRange.getRow(1);

    // Select the first row range to scroll the target cell to the top
    firstRowRange.select();

    // Scroll back to the target cell
    targetCell.select();
  } else {
    // If the target cell is already in the visible range, select it directly
    targetCell.select();
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there isn't a way to determine how many rows are visible on your screen, otherwise you could make this dynamic.
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active worksheet
    let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    // Define the target cell address
    let targetCellAddress = "A168";
    let theCell = activeSheet.getRange(targetCellAddress);
    activeSheet.getRange("A208").select();
    theCell.select()
    }

Comment: @jkpieterse Your code works as expected in Excel 365 desktop. With Excel online, A168 is the `bottom-left` cell.

Comment: @MONtana9999  It seems the intent for `Office Scripts` is closer integration with `Power Automate` as one step in broader flows, rather than standalone scripting. This results in some limitations compared to VBA, and it does not provide functionality to identify visible ranges as VBA (`ActiveWindow.VisibleRange`).